# Sort an array and add a rank field in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a User collection which stores each user's score and name in MongoDB.

when listing all users, I want to add a new field to it to give me the ranking of the user with respect to score

My solution is :

```js
async findRank() {
  const users = await User.find().sort({score: -1})
  let ObjectOfResults = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users))
  for (let index = 0; index < ObjectOfResults.length; index++) {
    ObjectOfResults[index].rank = index
  }
  return ObjectOfResults
}
```

So imagine we have very big data in here. Can I improve my solution using MongoDB operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method is good but just change the `results.length` to `user.length` but if you want using mongoDB operation do like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "score": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "",
      "items": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$items",
      "includeArrayIndex": "items.rank"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$items"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "score": -1
    }
  }
])
```

you can use `lean()` and `select` the some fields in `find` query to increase performance

```
async findRank() {
  const users = await User.find({},"_id score").sort({score: -1}).lean()
  for (let index = 0; index < users.length; index++) {
    users[index].rank = index
  }
  return users
}
if you want group by the documents based on name or score ... it's better use mongodb operation
```

Comment: Thanks, What do you about performance in big data?

Comment: your method has better performance, don't use aggregate for big data

Comment: Bu the way my method was not working. I edited and now its working. The results that comes from MongoDB is actually not the format of object so I needed to convert it. You have any idea about it?

Comment: how can i start from 1 instead of 0