# How to update a number field with sorting index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a `mongoose` user schema in my `nodejs` `express` api which looks like this;

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
display_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
points: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
rank: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
},
country:{
    type: String,
    required: true
}});
```

I want to create multiple user generator endpoint. First i will create a json object with random ids, usernames, points, countries and 0 rank. Then i will insert all of them with `mongoose` `insertMany()` function. Problem is i need to recalculate-set all ranks of documents in collection.

What i want to do, write a `mongoose` query which would sort all data on **points** and update **rank** with the sorting index (all of them). I couldn't find a proper solution for it so i could use some help. Thanks in advance.

Note:I also want to give the same rank to the users who have the same points, this makes it a little more complicated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091970/sort-an-array-and-add-a-rank-field-in-mongodb/66093425#66093425 Check this answer maybe help you

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi Thanks for the comment. I've checked it. Similar to my problem yes, but i was looking more like an update query like i could create with sql. I've seen some articles that say it is not possible to do exactly what i want. I've changed my algorithm anyway. Best